# Magento v1.3.2.4 - 2 domains using one database

Tags: error, multistore, magento-1.3

It's been a rough day.  I am the IT generalist for my employer.  Employer has 2 domains, each have Magento maintaining their product catalog, but both in the same Magento admin area (shared database?).  Last night, the server admin upgraded PHP to 5.3 for the server.  When I came in, the product catalog was erroring out with:
Fatal Error: Method Varien Object: __toString() cannot take arguments.  I googled and found a mean to find/replace the 'toString' references and change them to 'invoke'.  Now the primary domain is working well, with no errors when attempting to view the products catalog.

The second domain is not working in that same way.  It appears it is pointing to an empty directory in /products/report.  The problem only is affecting the products tab.  The other tabs are maintained by 'Expression Engine'.

[image: how it looked before fixing toString]
[image: how it looks after implementing the toString fix]
[image: the magento admin showing the two domain's catalog layout]

So the main domain works perfectly now.  But I can't figure out how to make whatever is drawing the nav bar, aim for the proper menu.

Any advice?  I could really use some right about now.

Comment: I completely agree with Fabian that you really should update Magento. That said, a simple google search for "magento 1.3 php 5.3" will turn up a number of blogs that show you what sort of code changes you would need to make for Magento to run on PHP 5.3 without causing these errors. Additionally, you should also consider disabling error printing. They should be logged, but never sent to the browser on a production site.

Comment: I did google first thing, and found the set of changes necessary to get the first domain working, but the reason for my post here was that there are two domains working off of one magento database.  The second domain still had the issue, so was looking for a magento wizard to advise me on how to fix production.  As I reverted to backup, the new correct path is to see about migrating the magento to a more secure and better updated webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend to update magento to a proper version. PHP 5.4 is out of active support http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Your problem should be fixed with a proper PHP and magento version.

Beside this, Magento 1.3 and PHP 5.3 are out of security patch support for a long time and I assume you don'T pay anyone to backport the current patches?

Answer (score 3):

Fabian, 
You are absolutely right.  The environment does need major updating.  As I am the relatively new IT generalist here, I will make that a project to create a new webserver and migrate sites to that current unit.

My question was more on looking for answers on how to solve the issue in the current environment.  Upgrading one component led to problems, so I am sure upgrading more would lead to more issues.

I ended up doing a full restore of the box from the previous night's backup, lost a few hours of production data, but things are back to the status quo.

Thank you for your advice.
  eric

Comment: Welcome To SE. If an answer helps you solve your problem, you should accept the answer. Your answer does not look like a solution.

Comment: While my answer did not solve the riddle of the original post and as no one was able to offer suggestions on how to solve my conundrum, it solved the stress the users were feeling.  Now that I am back at square one, I can plan in a project the correct long term solution, which is migrating the magento database to a more secure and better updated webserver.